# Add Apache Directory Studio as favorite to Ubuntu dock should not open new "icon"

Tags: launcher, gnome-shell

I want to have Apache Directory Studio in Ubuntu 23.04 dock.

I have created this desktop file

```
~/.local/share/applications$ cat ApacheDirectoryStudio.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=ApacheDirectoryStudio 
Path=/home/myuser/ApacheDirectoryStudio/
Exec=/home/myuser/ApacheDirectoryStudio/ApacheDirectoryStudio
Icon=/home/myuser/ApacheDirectoryStudio/icon.xpm
```

Also I have added u+x permission to this file

And now I can see proper icon in application search window. I can click on it with right button mouse and "Add to favourites" which will make nice icon and make it visible when I call

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

However when I click on the blue Apache Directory Studio Icon, new window opens I suppose because separate java process starts and gray gear icon appeard and is higlighted as opened instead. See image bellow. Is it possible to have just the blue icon there?

[image: I can see two icons instead of one]

Comment: I have tried to have java command (got using ps command) in Exec parameter of desktop application, but that doesn't help.